# Why SharePoint return TOO MANY REQUESTS for 401 HTTP code?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, office365, csom

I develop simple application for fetching data in SharePoint sites. I use requests from [SharePoint REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service) for getting SharePoint Sites info (both for Team Sites and Communication Sites). Also I use such API for getting info about [files and folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest) in SharePoint document libraries.

Sometimes I get throttling responses from Microsoft with 429 HTTP code and
"429 TOO MANY REQUESTS" message in reply body.

But recently I noticed strange behavior: "429 TOO MANY REQUESTS" message returned in reply body but HTTP status code is 401 (which status for UNAUTHORIZED request). However I handle 401 HTTP status code in different way and this totally break the logic of my service and 401 HTTP status code in general.

I think it's not normal behavior, is it? How can I determine if 401 HTTP status code states for throttling of for unauthorized request? Straightforward reply body parsing is not a good approach as I think.

Comment: According to your description, I suppose that the SharePoint API side will ban your account or the corresponding API interface after too many requests. So you get a response code of 401. I am not sure about this problem, you can [ask a question on GitHub](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues), consult the SharePoint development team for more assistance.